# DateTime Field shows invalid format error while passing empty value through form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I trying to submit form while keeping field for datetime as empty which results in an error showing invalid format for datetime.

my modal

```
class lead(models.Model):
    assigned_to=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ref=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    lead_type=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    priority=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hot=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    source=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    mls_lead=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    auto_imported=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    inquiry_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    lead_closed_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    created_by=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    property_id=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    contact_id=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
```

its clear that i have  given null true for the datetime field and the form
i have is
 my form

```
class leads_form(forms.Form):
    assigned_to = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(o.id, str(o.username)) for o in CustomUser.objects.all()],required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    ref = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    lead_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.lead_type_dict.items(),required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct'}))
    priority = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.priority_dict.items(),required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct'}))
    hot = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.hot_dict.items(),required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct'}))
    source = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.source_dict.items(),required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct'}))
    mls_lead = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.true_false_dict.items(),required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct'}))
    auto_imported = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.true_false_dict.items(),required=False,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct'}))
    inquiry_date = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    lead_closed_date = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    created_by = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    property_id =  forms.IntegerField(required=False,widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    set_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dicto.set_status_dict.items(),required=True,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control slct','placeholder':'set status','required':'true'}))
    contact=forms.IntegerField(required=True,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'required':'true'}))
```

and when i try to create object of model with validate form data it shows

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

the way i create object is as follows

```
if form.is_valid():
            lead.objects.create(
                assigned_to=form.cleaned_data['assigned_to'],
                ref=form.cleaned_data['ref'],
                lead_type=form.cleaned_data['lead_type'],
                priority=form.cleaned_data['priority'],
                hot=form.cleaned_data['hot'],
                source=form.cleaned_data['source'],
                mls_lead=form.cleaned_data['mls_lead'],
                auto_imported=form.cleaned_data['auto_imported'],
                inquiry_date=form.cleaned_data['inquiry_date'],
                lead_closed_date=form.cleaned_data['lead_closed_date'],
                created_by=form.cleaned_data['created_by'],
                property_id=form.cleaned_data['property_id'],
                contact_id=form.cleaned_data['contact'])
```

Comment: Empty string is not an acceptable value for datetime field. You need to either omit it or set it to None.

Comment: but i need to keep it empty. how can i do it?

Comment: In databases, empty is not a valid value for datetime type. You have options to set the field value to null which in Python is equivalent to None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Django's `DateTimeField`, a blank string is not the same as `None` (or null). I believe this confusion comes from the similar evaluation of truth values for a blank string and `None`.

To assert no error is raised and the field is populated with a null value when wanted, rework `DateTimeField` populating lines like this one (from the `lead.objects.create` call):

```
lead_closed_date=form.cleaned_data['lead_closed_date']
```

to this:

```
lead_closed_date=(
    form.cleaned_data['lead_closed_date'] 
    if form.cleaned_data['lead_closed_date'] 
    else None
)
```

With this correction, it will populate the value of `lead_closed_date` with `form.cleaned_date['lead_closed_date']` if the *truth* value of `form.cleaned_data['lead_closed_date']` is `True`.