# how do I properly set up data validation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF class which receives JSON date  and after it has been processed, create new database instances.

```
class CsvToDatabase(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        print()
        for _, vendor in data.items():
            v = Vendors(
                vendor_name=vendor['Vendor'],
                country=vendor['Country'],
                nda=vendor['NDA date'],

            )
            try:
                v.full_clean()
            except ValidationError as e:
                data = ({'status': str(e)})
                return Response(data, content_type='application/json')
            v.save()
        return Response({'received data': request.data,
                         'message': 'Vendors from vendors_list were successfully added to the database'})
```

**models.py**

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = tuple(countries)

    ...
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
    nda = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

tuple(countries) looks like:

```
(..., ('AR', 'Argentina'), ('AM', 'Armenia'), ('AW', 'Aruba'), ('AU', 'Australia'), ('AT', 'Austria'), ('AZ', 'Azerbaijan'), ('BS', 'Bahamas'), ('BH', 'Bahrain'), ('BD', 'Bangladesh'), ('BB', 'Barbados'), ('BY', 'Belarus'), ('BE', 'Belgium'), ...)
```

Received JSON data may or may not contain the value of the **nda** field. An example of an incoming data format is as follows

```
{
    "1": {
        "Vendor": "Firstvendortestname",
        "Country": "Belgium,",
        "NDA date": "",
        "Primary Contact Name": "Jack Jhonson",
        "Primary Contact Email": "jack@gmail.com",
        "Secondary Contact Name": "Jack2 Jhonson",
        "Secondary Contact Email": "jack2@gmail.com",
        "Modules": "Module1, Module2"
    },
    "2": {
        "Vendor": "Secondvendortestname",
        "Country": "Belarus",
        "NDA date": "2019-12-24",
        "Primary Contact Name": "Sandra Bullock",
        "Primary Contact Email": "sandra@gmail.com",
        "Secondary Contact Name": "Sandra Bullock",
        "Secondary Contact Email": "sandra@gmail.com",
        "Modules": "Module1, Module2"
    }
}
```

**What's the problem.**

A first one - `"Country": "Belgium,"` get me error

```
{
    "status": "{'country': [\"Value 'Belgium' is not a valid choice.\"]}"
}
```

But if I change to `"Country": "BE,"` it works.

A second one - `"NDA date": ""`, get me error

```
ValidationError at /api/v1/vendors/from_csv_create/
["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/vendors/from_csv_create/
Django Version: 2.2.9
....
.....
```

But at models I have `null=True` and `blank=True`. And what is strange is that the second error is printed in *text* format instead of *json* as the first. Although in the exception, I specify `return Response(data, content_type='application/json')`.

How do I get the ability to work with an empty *nda* field and set up my work with?

Comment: If your view receives data that must be validated, you should be using a Serializer to validate the data. It kind of is similar to the `Form` concept from django. You will specify which fields are expected, which are required, or even define custom validation functions using `def validate_myfield(self, value):` Check out their page: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: @JordanKowal Yes, I know about serializer, but I think this way should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st problem, it's because "Belgium" is not in your choices. Choice tuples are basically `(accepted_value, human_readable_value)`. So when you write `("BE", "Belgium")`, only "BE" will be considered as a valid choice. And it will be SHOWN as "Belgium" in your admin.

If you wanted to accept both (which might not be necessary), there are several ways to go:

- Add more tuples : `(("BE", "Belgium"), ("Belgium", "Belgium"))`
- Create a custom validator for the field

For your 2nd error `"" is not valid date`, it's because an empty string is not a valid value for a Date object in Django. Check out this topic, who had the same issue : [DateTime Field shows invalid format error while passing empty value through form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646302/datetime-field-shows-invalid-format-error-while-passing-empty-value-through-form)

Basically, you should either OMIT the field, or replace the "" value with `None` before pushing it

Comment: Thanks, its good points to problem understandings. I think I'll created new list of choices `("Belgium", "Belgium")` because I dont need both way. But the most interesting part is how to replace empty string from json to `None` value. Do you have any thoughts about that?

Comment: I seem to have obtained the desired result by changing the `clean` model method.

Comment: Yes, using .clean() is the recommended way to "intercept, control, and possibily change" incoming data.